# Bug when trying to create view with 2 UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

I'm attempting to create a view with two UIButtons. The code compiles without any error but the buttons don't have any labels and they can't be clicked.
[image]

```
-(id)initWithTabBar {

if ([self init]) {
    self.title = @"Tab1";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"promoters.png"];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Nav 1";
}

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookAuthorize) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];

[self.view addSubview:button];

[button release];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button2 setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 100, 100)];

[self.view addSubview:button2];

[button2 release];

return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't release those buttons. They are created as autoreleased objects. As described in [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html):

> You only release or autorelease
>   objects you own. You take ownership of
>   an object if you create it using a
>   method whose name **begins with “alloc”,
>   “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”**

None of these words appear in **buttonWithType:**, so you don't take responsibility and you are safe to assume it's autoreleased.

Comment: Oh I get it, so buttonWithType: is a static class method that handles memory allocation?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, the buttons cant be named when it is withType. The code to make the words appear in the uibutton is:

```
  UIButton *someButton=[[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 6, 175, 36)]autorelease];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[someButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:someButton];
```